# Interop with Microsoft Access does not interact with User's session

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, vba, interop

I am injecting a piece of VBA code into a Microsoft Access database from .Net.

It is just a single line of code, which runs a Macro. All the Macro does is run a block of VBA code inside a module.

The issue I am having is that this all happens in a new MSAccess session, which I can't even see, instead of the session the user currently has open.

Is it possible to, instead, have this interact with the users current MSAccess session? The whole point of this is to open a particular form inside the MSAccess session on every occurence of a .Net event. My C# code is below:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

var msAccess = new Application();

msAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"x:\foo\bar.accdb", false);
msAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro("macCTI");
msAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single instance of Access running you could use **[`Marshal.GetActiveObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices
...
try
{
    var msAccess = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application");
    msAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro("macCTI");
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
    // handle error
}
```

Alternatively, if more than one are running, and no two instances have the same database open, you could use **[`Marshal.BindToMoniker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.bindtomoniker.aspx)**:

```
var msAccess = (Application) Marshal.BindToMoniker(@"x:\foo\bar.accdb");
```

---

> <sup>**Note:** This [Microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126) has this to say:</sup>
>
> <sup>Whether a COM server is Single Use (Multiple Instances) or
>   Multiuse (Single Instance) might affect your decision to use
>   GetActiveObject to get reference to that server. Because potentially
>   more than one instance of Word, Excel, or Microsoft Access can be
>   running, GetActiveObject on a particular server may return an instance
>   that you did not expect. The instance that is first registered in the
>   ROT is typically the instance that is returned by GetActiveObject. If
>   you want to get an Automation Reference to a specific running instance
>   of Word, Excel, or Microsoft Access, use BindToMoniker with the name
>   of the file that is opened in that instance. For a Multiuse (Single
>   Instance) server like PowerPoint, it does not matter, because the
>   automation reference points to the same running instance.</sup>

Comment: Thankyou. Our users usually have multiple instances of Access running, `Marshal.GetActiveObject` seems to return the first instance started. Is there any way to be specific about the instance of Access I want to work with?

Answer (score 0):

To not get a new Access instance you will have to see if an instance already exists. Use `Marshal.GetActiveObject` as Matt suggested:

```
Application GetAccessApplication() {
  var application = (Application) Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application");
  return application ?? new Application();
}
```

Notice that there is a slight disconnect here because you have to use the ProgID to get an existing instance of Access but to create a new instance you use the interop assembly.

You can then make the Access application visible:

```
var msAccess = GetAccessApplication();
msAccess.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I have got this far now. This still starts a new instance of Access, I want to interact with the current session.